# While loop not taking 'if' statement into account

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program in Python where the user is asked to input a number of hours after which a countdown starts in seconds, however I want to also make sure that no floats/strings are inputted and if they are, the user needs to be prompted with the same question and input a correct value. If an integer is inputted then I want the program to jump to the next statement (hence 'pass' on line 4). However, whatever I type in, the program always jumps to the next statement, regardless of whether it's a string or a float.

```
TimeHours = input("Countdown time in hours:")

while isinstance(TimeHours, int) is True:
    pass
    if float(TimeHours) / 1 != int(float(TimeHours)):
        input('Please input a whole number, decimals are not accepted.')
    elif isinstance(TimeHours, str):
            input('Alphabetical letters or unknown characters are not allowed, e.g. A, B, C, (, *')
            continue
```

I tried using if statements and defining functions, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: `isinstance(TimeHours, int)` is never `True`.

Comment: If I remove 'pass' it does the same thing for some reason. Also, I need it to pass if the answer is an integer, and if it's not i want it to error and restart the statement.

Comment: @erip `pass` is no-op it does not matter in this case

Comment: The return of input() is always a string, never an integer or a float or anything else (unless you're still using Python 2). If you need a number, you have to convert the string to a number yourself.

Comment: `input` always be str

Comment: @erip What's your point?

Comment: @Noria So, to put it another way, you just want integer values input. The best way to manage that is to pass the input string to *int()* and manage any exception (ValueError) that arises

Comment: @Fred this is what I ended up doing and it solved the problem, thank you.

Comment: Your code under elif is not properly indented

Answer (score -2, accepted):

like this

```
while True:
    TimeHours = input("Countdown time in hours:")
    try:
        TimeHours = int(TimeHours)
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print('Alphabetical letters or unknown characters are not allowed, e.g. A, B, C, (, *')
        continue
```

Comment: And you still need to edit your code as `Yevhen Kuzmovych` said

Comment: If you re-read the question you'll see that the requirement is for integer values

Comment: Can you explain a couple of things? 1) Why do you attempt conversion to float? 2) Why are you dividing by 1?

Comment: In fact, you will notice that my source code was modified for the questioner, and I also said that he still needs to modify the code based on the other person's answer. Make final changes

Answer (score 1):

Write a function that returns an integer value and which handles any problems with the user input. Something like this:

```
def get_time():
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input('Countdown time in hours: '))
        except ValueError:
            print('Whole numbers only please')
```

Answer (score 0):

`float(TimeHours) / 1` returns `float`. Did you mean `float(TimeHours) // 1`. And `isinstance(TimeHours, str)` can not be `True` as it is checked only if `isinstance(TimeHours, int) is True`. So it doesn't ignore the `if` and `elif`, it just never enters them.

Side note:

`isinstance(TimeHours, int) is True` is redundant, just use `isinstance(TimeHours, int)` instead.

Comment: So if the input is 2.5 for example, i want it to return float so it prints the error ('no decimals allowed'). Does float(TimeHours) return float even if the input is integer?

Comment: `input` always returns a string (assuming you're using python3). You can convert it to `float` with `float(TimeHours)`. You can convert `'2.5'` to integer by converting it to float and then to int : `int(float(TimeHours))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can:

- get user input
- check if it's numeric (since the input is always a string you can use this method)
- print a message if it's not and start the loop over
- cast to integer and break from the loop if it is

```py
while True:
    time_hours = input("Countdown time in hours:")
    if time_hours.isnumeric() is False:
        print("Please input a whole number. Decimals, alphabetical letters or unknown characters are not allowed.")
        continue
    time_hours = int(time_hours)
    break
```

Side notes:

- python likes sneak_case
- dividing even using `//` does NOT always yield an integer (see for yourself e.g. `print(type(2//3.))` in REPL)
- python has strong (and dynamic, but that doesn't matter here) typing , so you have to be explicit about type casting

Comment: @toyotaSupra There ain't no tkinter stuff in my answer, as this is completely off topic imho...your comment is under not the related answer

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a function instead of a while loop. Mostly because I use tkinter in everything I do so while loops are out of the question.

You can build a function to handle the check like this:

```
def get_time_in_hours_from_user(message=None):
    global time_hours
    if message is not None:
        print(message)
    th = input("Countdown time in hours:")
    if th.isdigit():
        time_hours = th
        print(f'The value provided is a valid integer: {th}')
        # Provide the rest of your executable code here or reference another function to execute code.
    else:
        print(f'The value provided is not a valid integer: {th}')
        get_time_in_hours_from_user()

get_time_in_hours_from_user()
```

Results:

```
Countdown time in hours:2.2
The value provided is not a valid integer: 2.2
Countdown time in hours:abc
The value provided is not a valid integer: abc
Countdown time in hours:5
The value provided is a valid integer: 5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Alternatively if you want the user to provide a value in a GUI you can do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(root, text='Countdown time in hours:').grid(row=0, column=0)
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

def get_time_in_hours_from_user(message=None):
    global time_hours
    if message is not None:
        print(message)
    th = entry.get().strip()
    if th.isdigit():
        time_hours = th
        lbl['text'] = f'The value provided is a valid integer: {th}'
        # Provide the rest of your executable code here or reference another function to execute code.
    else:
        lbl['text'] = f'The value provided is not a valid integer: {th}'

tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=get_time_in_hours_from_user).grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')
lbl = tk.Label(root)
lbl.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='ew')


root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]